# How can I make underbrace texts have the normal-text size?

Tags: fontsize

## Situation

I am using `\underbrace` with `\substack` for multi-line underbracing. The problem is that the text under the brace is small relative to the normal text. I want to make the size of texts under braces **the same** to that of normal texts.

## Example

Here is an example:

```
\implies \underbrace{x(t) = z(t)}_{\substack{x(t)=y(t)\\y(t)=z(t)}}
```

[image: Not what I want]

As you see, the formulas under the brace are small relative to the normal formulas. It seems like their size is subscripts' size.
I want something like this:

[image: What I want]

## Notes

Commands like `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\normalfont` in the underbrace did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\scriptstyle` is hardcoded into environment `subarray`, which is used by `\substack`. As workaround, `\scriptstyle` can be locally redefined as `\textstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \implies \underbrace{x(t) = z(t)}_{%
    \let\scriptstyle\textstyle
    \substack{x(t)=y(t)\\y(t)=z(t)}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A cleaner result can be achieved by using environment `array` together with `\textstyle`. This fixes also the too narrow line spacing of `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \implies \underbrace{x(t) = z(t)}_{%
    \textstyle
    \begin{array}{c}
      x(t)=y(t)\\
      y(t)=z(t)
    \end{array}
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with array]

And a third variant using `gathered`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \implies \underbrace{x(t) = z(t)}_{%
    \textstyle
    \begin{gathered}
      x(t) = y(t)\\
      y(t) = z(t)
    \end{gathered}
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with gathered]

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, it was a copy&paste error.

Comment: Is there any `footnotestyle`?

Comment: @alper, the math styles are `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bunderbrace}[2]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
  \underbrace{#1}\\
  #2
  \end{array}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\implies
\bunderbrace{x(t) = z(t)}{x(t)=y(t)\\y(t)=z(t)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the underbraced part inside matrix environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\implies \underbrace{x(t) = z(t)}_{\begin{matrix}{x(t)=y(t)}\\{y(t)=z(t)}\end{matrix}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]